# Print Generated Barcode / QR Code On Receipt

Tags: android, printing

Hello I am new to android, I am currently trying to print a receipt from my Android 4.4.2 table to my Zicox thermal receipt printer.  I have been able to print the text so far but now I need to go a step further and print barcodes / qrcodes.  Unfortunately this is way beyond my knowledge, I have googled solutions and have not found one for me yet.

These are the methods I use to generate my barcode:

```
    /**************************************************************
     * getting from com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.QRCodeEncoder
     *
     * See the sites below
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/EncodeActivity.java
     * http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java
     */

    private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

    Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
        String contentsToEncode = contents;
        if (contentsToEncode == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
        if (encoding != null) {
            hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result;
        try {
            result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            // Unsupported format
            return null;
        }
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
        // Very crude at the moment
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
            if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
                return "UTF-8";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my onClick method that starts the entire process:

```
// barcode data
        String barcode_data = "123456";

        // barcode image
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        try {
            barCode = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_data, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 300, 40);
            // bitmap.getRowBytes();
            iv.setImageBitmap(barCode);

        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        innerLayout.addView(iv);
```

So now I am basically able to generate and display the barcode now I want to be able to print in on my receipts.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your question, you basically want to print a bitmap, that contains the QR code.

You can use [PrintHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper.html) class for the same. Here's a sample code from the official documentation that shows how to use it.

```
private void doPhotoPrint() {
PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.droids);
photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
```

}

Also, it says :

*After the printBitmap() method is called, no further action from your application is required. The Android print user interface appears, allowing the user to select a printer and printing options.*

**Update :**

The above method prints only a bitmap. For printing a whole layout (like a receipt, as you said), instructions have been laid out [here](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html). I'll try to summarize it for you here :

The first step is to to extend [PrintDocumentAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html) class and override certain methods. In that adapter, there's a callback method known as `onWrite()` that is called for drawing content on the file to be printed. In this method, you'll have to use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) object to draw content. This object has all the helper methods to draw bitmap/line/text etc.

Then, when the print is requested, obtain an instance of `PrintManager' class  as follows :

```
 PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

Then, call the print method as :

```
 printManager.print(jobName, new CustomDocumentAdapter(getActivity()),
        null);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Quick question, is this image alone? Because it's a receipt so there is going to be more than just a barcode or qrcode on it.

Comment: @user3718908:  Edited as per your requirement.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your time, will try this out, wondering why it got a downvote though. :)